# Using local labels after switching sections inside a macro

Tags: macros, nasm

Suppose, we have a macro that writes code into `.data` and `.text` sections:

```
%macro my_macro 0
[section .data]
table dd 1024
[section .text]
dec eax         ; some commmands
%endmacro

global _start
section .text:
_start:
    jmp .label_jump
    my_macro

.label_jump:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

If we have a local label placed after the macro call, it is impossible to jump to it above the macro call:

```
$ nasm test29.asm
test.asm:11: error: symbol `_start.label_jump' undefined
```

Is it possible to use the local labels in such circumstances?

Comment: Use labels with `%%` at the start, these will be scoped to the m-macro and not interfere with local labels. Internally NASM will expand these to start with `..@` which you can also use directly if you prefer. The dot dot at prefix makes it so that a label is not considered a base label for local labels. You could also use `table equ $` instead, which will also not be considered a base label for local labels.

Comment: @ecm Actually, the question was not about the local macro labels, but the ordinary local label `.label_jump`, which was unusable in command `jmp .label_jump` issued before the macro call.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's because the `table` label defined by your m-macro is taken as a new base label for local labels that start with a single dot. The local label `.label_jump` will expand to `table.label_jump` whereas your `jmp` will expand to branching to `_start.label_jump`. You have to use an `equ` or a label prefixed by `%%` or `..@` in the m-macro so that `.label_jump:` will define the full label `_start.label_jump` rather than what it does now.

Comment: @ecm I can not make `table` a local macro label as it is used later in the code. Neither I can make it  a label using equ as it contains a list of addresses where I would jump depending upon the value of eax register..

Comment: Three solutions: `%define` a single-line macro to the macro-local label eg `%define TABLE %%table` then use the define later. Use a `..@` non-local label eg `..@table:`, this is not used for the base of a local label but not macro-local either so you can reference `..@table` later. Or finally do use an equate. I don't mean equate instead of variable, I mean instead of `table: dd 1024` you split the definition into two lines, `table: equ $` followed by the data like `dd 1024`. This way of specifying a label is exactly like just `table:` except it is not considered for the base of local labels.

Comment: In any case, switching sections is absolutely irrelevant to the local label and multi-line macro interaction.

Comment: `%%table: dd 1024` then `table equ %%table` (still within the m-macro) should work too. ETA: Confirmed with a test.

Comment: @ecm Local macro label worked. Thank you.